# Image clipping by concave polygons on OpenCL

Tags: image, opencl, polygon, clipping, image-clipping

Is image polygon clipping possible directly on OpenCL? Or is OpenGL interoperability necessary for this?

If this is possible directly on OpenCL, I think this problem could be reduced to the filling of concave polygons changing the alpha channel; in fact I would like using a (native) kernel having as parameters the image (image2d_t) and the polygon (uint2 array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, polygon clipping is not directly available in OpenCL.

You could use OpenCL/OpenGL interop, or write a parallel scan-conversion function in OpenCL.